# ManyToMany relation with DQL query

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, dql

On my website I have Users and Formations. I want that User can add Formations to their favorites. SO I did a ManyToMany relation on my User:

```
/**
     * Many User have Many Phonenumbers.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Formation")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_favorites",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="formation_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $favorites;
```

It created users_favorites in my BDD, with the ids of the user and formation. Now I'm trying to query on this, I want to get all the Formations with the users that added this formation to their favorites. Here's what I tried:

```
public function findAllWithFormation(){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('formation')
            ->leftJoin('formation.favorites', 'user')
            ->addSelect('formation')
            ->addSelect('user')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
            ;
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 100 near 'user': Error: Class App\Entity\Formation has no association named favorites
```

I don't know how to use the user_favorites table to make it work. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend adding in your entity the name annotation.

```
@ORM\Table(name="formation")
```

That way the query build will know to what entity you are refering.

Hope this helps, stay safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added the name annotation on my two entities but stil the same error.

Comment: OKay it worked, but I the result isn't what I would have liked ^^

Comment: explain more the result that you were searching. Maybe i can help

Comment: I did another post since it was another subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630943/dql-queries-not-returning-what-i-would-like?noredirect=1#comment114278108_64630943

Comment: Glad you found the solution. Good luck, take care and stay safe :D